# Regex data validation for input containing only the digits

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to prompt the user to input a data value, and check that the string they enter only contains the digits 0-9:

```
class String
    def validate(regex)
        !self[regex].nil?
    end
end

regex = /\A[0-9]\z/

validInput = false
until validInput
    puts "Enter digits: "
    input = gets.chomp
    if !input.validate(regex)
        puts "Invalid input. Seeking integer."
    else
        validInput = true

    end
end
```

However this loop returns `false` on everything other than single digits excluding `0`. I previously had this working with `regex = /\A[1-9]\z/`, but I going back to where it was working, it doesn't anymore, and this also means the user can't enter `0`.

How can I use a regex to validate that user input only contains the digits 0-9?

Comment: Why are those new to SO in such a rush to select an answer? Take it easy. Give it some time. There's no rush. You don't want to discourage other answers and have some consideration for members still working on their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `+` quantifier after `[1-9]`(Shouldn't it be `[0-9]` is you want digits from 0 to 9?). i.e. `regex = /\A[0-9]+\z/`

You can represent the character class `[0-9]` as `\d` so that the regex looks neater: `\A\d+\z`

The `+` checks for one(minimum) or more occurrences of a digit in the string. Right now, you are checking for presence of only **ONE** digit.

Comment: Thanks for this :) Accept in 7 mins

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP asked for "regex to validate that user input only contains the digits 0-9?"

Comment: `/\A[0-9]+\z/` is customarily written `/\A\d+\z/`.

Comment: How can I extend this to include a single decimal point (.)? So the user can enter 10.2 but not 10.2.2 or 10..2

Comment: @Nemo Modify it to `\A[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\z`, here the `?` is a quantifier that matches for either **no** occurrence or **one** occurrence. `\A\d+(\.\d+)?\z` looks neater though. :)

Comment: Thanks :) Still looks like an alien language to me but I'm getting there hah

Comment: @Nemo it will appear tough at first :) I suggest you read **Mastering Regular Expressions** by *Jeffrey E.F. Friedl* to understand regexs better.

Comment: @Nemo,  you could use a non-capture group like this: `(?:\d+|\d+\.\d+)`. This excludes `"2."` and `".2" `. If you want to include those: `(?:\d+|\d*\.\d+|\d+\.\d*)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
s !~ /\D/
```

.....................